Auth Provider Auth0 ID different to PostGreSQL ID - how to effectively use @PreAuthorize in Spring Boot
In my Spring App, I realise I have a slight problem.
I authorize through Auth0, which sends back an access token, with the Auth0 generated user ID.
My PostGreSQL database, behind my Spring App, allocates it's own user ID (via the normal auto increment, as a primary key)
Get Requests
To be able to do get requests, in my Spring App, I implemented the following two tables
@Table(name = "user_tbl")
data class UserEntitySQL(
    @Id
    val id: Long? = null,        // ID assigned by the database, if null
    val firstname: String,
    val lastname: String,
    val age: Int
)

@Table(name = "user_identity")
data class UserIdentity(
    @Id
    val id: Long? = null,        // ID assigned by the database, if null
    val provider: String,        // The identity provider (Auth0, Cognito, etc.)
    val providerId: String,      // The unique ID from the identity provider
    val userId: Long             // Foreign key to the User table
)

The reason I do this is because, when I try to get the users profile, in my Spring App, I only really have access to information in the Jwt token (which has the Auth0 issued user id)
So, to get the user's profile I make an SQL request like this (it is effectively using the Auth0 issued user ID, which I have, and then gets the PostgresID via the user_entity table:
SELECT u.*
FROM user_tbl u
JOIN user_identity_tbl ui ON u.id = ui.user_id
WHERE ui.provider = :provider
AND ui.provider_id = :providerId

This is good for get requests, as I only make one request to the database.
Further, here when hitting the end point /getUser/me, I don't need to annotate this with @PreAuthorize, as it will only get the currently logged in users profile
Mutating Requests
I'm not sure how to do this effecitvely with Put Requests. Any incoming JSON will have the fields (id, firstname, lastname, age)
So, at this stage, I cannot use @PreAuthorize(JwtToken.token.sub = JSON ID) - as a check to prevent a user for accessing /putUser/me or /deleteUser/me
It seems that to update a record, I would have to

Fetch the Auth0 ID from the UserEntity table (based on the JSON ID)
In Spring, check that it matches JwtToken.token.sub
If it does, allow the update to be made, otherwise throw access denied

This seems ok, except that if the user is not authorized, I am making a needless call to the SQL Database.
(I know I could ignore the incoming JSON USER ID, and just replace that with JwtToken.token.sub OR I could try to get Auth0 to access my PostGresSQL database and add the PostGreSQL user ID at the time it creates the access token, via it's Actions feature?)
What if a user has the authority to update another related entity (like a contract).
If they were updating their own contract, I could replace the incoming JSON User ID in the contract, with JwtToken.token.sub. (or get Auth0 to add the UserID at the time it creates the access token, so I could do an @PreAuthorize check)
But what if that user has the authority to update another user's contract?
I don't want to replace USER ID in the incoming Contract JSON. I would want to access the database, get the contracts of the User ID in the JSON, check that one department matches the contracts of the user logged in JwtToken.token.sub (with authority to update other contracts apart from their own), then decide whether or not to permit the request. I suppose here, I'm going to have to make an SQL database call anyway... so it may not be an issue
Approaches
So I think my question boils down to mutating requests for entities of the currently logged in user only.
Should one.
a)

Fetch the Auth0 ID from the UserEntity table (based on the JSON ID)
In Spring, check that it matches JwtToken.token.sub
If it does, allow the update to be made, otherwise throw access denied
Requires at least one db call for every rest request to this endpoint

b)

Ignore the incoming JSON USER ID, and just replace that with JwtToken.token.sub
Requires at least one db call for every rest request to this endpoint

c)

Get Auth0 to add the UserID at the time it creates the access token, so I could do an @PreAuthorize check
Much kinder to the DB, as it requires no db calls (only 1 by Auth0, to add the PostGres ID to the access token)
But could potentially not permit issuance of access token, if db call fails

Or Architecturally, am I doing something wrong?
Current Configuration
My configuration so far is:
Angular > Spring BFF (interacts with Auth0; stores tokens in Redis) > Spring Rest API (Resource Server) > PostGreSQL
I'm only using Auth0, to store the Auth0 ID (auto generated), user's email, and user's password, in it's own native database feature. The Auth0 ID, and email get sent through via the access token, via the sub claim, and email via a custom claim.
